# React NavDropdown hides on click of any MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hello I am using react bootstrap, NavDropdown.
I have a Navbar in my application, and I want to put NavDropdown in Navbar but the default behaviour of NavDropdown hides the dropdown on click anywhere.

Solutions I have Used:

```
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
```

None of above is working for me.

My Code:

```
class CustomNavDropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavDropdown title={"Dropdown"}>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClick}>an item</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically my problem is that my NavDropdown hides if I click anywhere, I want it to hide only when I click on the `<ul>` tag, not the `<li>` tag or anywhere else in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved as follows:

```
class CustomNavDropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {menuIsOpened: false}
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }
  handleToggle(toggle) {
    //you code here, change state of menuIsOpened if you want to open or close
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavDropdown title={"Dropdown"} open={this.state.menuIsOpened} onToggle={this.handleToggle}>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClick}>an item</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

I put up event onToggle which is supported by NavDropdown and then we can handle the event in handleToggle and do whatever with it where toggle is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap Drop-down can be closed/opened via its prop "Open" by setting it as true or false. 
So basically when you click on the drop down, set the state as true, and when you click on the menuItem, set it as false, and there You go!

```
const [dropDownOpen, setdropDownOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

and drop down will be like:

```
<NavDropdown
  eventKey={index}
  open={dropDownOpen}
  key={`navItem_${index}`}
  onClick={() => {setdropDownOpen(true)}}
/>
```

and menuItem code will be like:

```
<MenuItem
  onClick={() => {setdropDownOpen(false)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it seems that `open` has been replaced by `show`. The logic to implement is the same.

(Modified example from @user1735921)

```
 class CustomNavDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {menuIsOpened: false}
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }
  handleToggle(toggle) {
    //you code here, change state of menuIsOpened if you want to open or close
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavDropdown title={"Dropdown"} show={this.state.menuIsOpened} onToggle={this.handleToggle}>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClick}>an item</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```